# как подключить образ «openindiana live usb» к виртуальной машине?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, solaris

уж много лет подключаю образы дисков такой командой:

```
$ vboxmanage storageattach имя.вм --storagectl "IDE" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium /путь/к/образу
```

сотни раз «всё было хорошо», а когда попытался подключить образ `OI-hipster-gui-20170502.usb` (взят со [страницы загрузок openindiana](https://www.openindiana.org/download/), наибыстрейшая отдача — со [словацкого зеркала](http://mirror.ynet.sk/openindiana/isos/hipster/latest/)), получил ошибку:

> VBoxManage: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium '/путь/к/OI-hipster-gui-20170502.usb' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
>   VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 178 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
>   VBoxManage: error: Invalid UUID or filename "/путь/к/OI-hipster-gui-20170502.usb"

подробности:

- файл читабелен
- его контрольная сумма проверена
- будучи записанным на *usb*-носитель, образ отлично загружается (ну, не то что бы отлично, но это уже проблемы слабой поддержки оборудования у *openindiana*)
- в том же каталоге лежит файл `OI-hipster-gui-20170502.iso` (из того же источника), который отлично подключается (и даже виртмашина с него загружается)
- дистрибутив: `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (xenial)`
- версия *virtualbox*: `5.0.40_Ubuntur115130` (последняя доступная из оф. репозитория для *xenial*, экспериментировать с «левыми» сборками возможности нет)
- проведённые в интернетах поиски строки `VBoxManage: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium` сводятся практически лишь к одному вердикту: «наверно, файл повреждён. скачайте заново»

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но пытались скачать повторно, к примеру, с другого зеркала?

Comment: @zombic, вообще скачивался образ дважды (т.е., из двух разных источников). но это лишнее ввиду совпадения контрольной суммы и наличия загружаемости после записи на usb-носитель.

Comment: Могу сказать, что у меня такая же ошибка. `VirtualBox 5.1.22_Ubuntu r115126`

Comment: Может нужен не `.usb`, а `.iso` образ?

Comment: @zombic, вариант «iso» отлично работает. об этом упомянуто в вопросе. нет, подключить нужно именно тот, у которого имя заканчивается на `usb`.